# Git + Smart Http(s): 403 Error

Tags: linux, git, apache, repository, smart-http

Although i have read many posts, I was not able to solve this problem.
I want to use Git + Smart Http, using a remote repository on my rasperry pi.
I'm running on Arch Linux.
First, let's consider an Http configuration (and not https), for semplicity.
Apache and Git are correctly installed on my Rasperry Pi, and the port for the Http connection is 8080.

On my Raspberry Pi: 
 1. I have uncommented in /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf the lines about mod_cgi, mod_alias, and mod_env 
 2. I have added to /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf these lines:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /srv/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/usr/lib/git-core*">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. I have created the directory /srv/git

   ```
   # mkdir -p /srv/git
   ```
4. I have created and initialized a git repository:

   ```
   # mkdir -p /srv/git/test.git
   ```

   ```
   # git init --bare
   ```
5. I have changed owner and group of the repo:

   ```
   # chown -R http:http /srv/git/test.git
   ```

On my client:

1. I have cloned the repo inside the folder

   ```
   $ git clone http://address:8080/git/test.git
   ```
2. I have created and added a new file and I have committed

   ```
   $ nano test.c
   ```

   ```
   $ git add test.c
   ```

   ```
   $ git commit -m 'first'
   ```
3. I have pushed the new project on my Rasperry Pi

   ```
   $ git push origin master
   ```

But I have this error:

```
atal: unable to access 'address:8080/git/test.git/';: The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: What version of Apache and Git are running on your server (the Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clone the repo *inside* the test folder (in which you initialized a git repo), that means you have:

```
test/test
```

If you are pushing from the first test folder, that repo would not have any origin.

Try in instead to remove any test folder, and start over with:

```
git clone http://address:8080/git/test.git
cd test
# work
git add .
git commit -m "work"
git push -u origin master
```

---

Regarding the 403 error, I would recommand on the server Apache (2.4) side:

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/git-core*">
   Options ExecCGI Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And:

```
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

Also, on the server, in the git bare repo folder:

```
cd /srv/git/test.git
git config --file config http.receivepack true
```

Comment: Thanks, new problem:
fatal: unable to access 'http://address:8080/git/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: @PenguinEngineer What version of Apache and Git are running on your server (the Raspberry Pi) ?

Comment: PS: I have edited the initial question, now it is present only the 403 error

Comment: Using apachectl -V command:
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)

Comment: @PenguinEngineer OK. And Git?

Comment: What about permissions of folders? Any tips?

Comment: @PenguinEngineer Make sure you have 755 for the folder served by the Apache process (which should be run as root or as a user account with write access on those folders)

Comment: @PenguinEngineer What do you see in Apache errors.log?

Comment: So, the folder has 755, but owner and group of the folder test.git is http (but I think this is correct)

Comment: @PenguinEngineer OK, let's check the errors.log then

Comment: Last line of my error.log file:
[Mon Sep 26 13:07:00.758977 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 23641] [client 131.114.234.82:38630] AH01215: Service not enabled: 'receive-pack': /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend

Comment: I think my server is two hours behind, but I think it's not a problem

Comment: @PenguinEngineer Do you have `<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">` and `<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">` sections in your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @PenguinEngineer That is for anonymous public push. For authenticated push, see http://superuser.com/a/933933/141

Comment: I have tried with anonymous configuration: same error and same log file

Comment: Good! Now it works! Thanks.
Should I edit the question?